# Is it feasible to host a website from within a virtual machine? Where would I begin?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, virtualhost, web-hosting

I'm developing a website (written in PHP) whose backend will communicate with quite a few binary applications also installed on the machine. I want to host this website on a VPS that also hosts a few other websites. However, I feel like it'd be bad form to just install all the necessary binary applications on the main VPS where they could theoretically interact with any of the other website. So I feel like I should "quarantine" the entire website and its dependencies (Apache, MySQL, PHP and then the other programs that it depends on) in a virtual machine.

My first question is - would this run okay? That's a very general question, but my benchmark is essentially "There is a negligible speed difference compared to just hosting it in the main VPS".

And secondly, what kind of steps would I need to follow to achieve this? I know how to set up a virtual machine, and I can set up virtual hosts in Apache... but how would I make it so that when someone type mysite.com, Apache (on the host machine) looks at the virtual host configuration for mysite.com and goes "Right, I need to serve up the contents from this virtual machine"?

Comment: `Is it feasible to host a website from within a virtual machine?` - Yes.  `Where would I begin?` - At the beginning.

Comment: VPSes are typically VMs to start with. Layering VMs on VMs is generally not a good idea. Host the binaries on a separate VPS and have them interact via an API.

Comment: @joeqwerty Okay, thanks. Does all of your reputation just come from sarky comments?

Comment: That wasn't snark. That was an attempt to be concise and to the point. Is it feasible? Yes, completely. Untold numbers of websites are hosted on virtual machines. Where do you begin? At the beginning. How would you build a website on a physical server or a virtual private server? The steps are the same with a virtual machine.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'll repeat myself then, how would I make it so that when someone type mysite.com, Apache (on the host machine) looks at the virtual host configuration for mysite.com and goes "Right, I need to serve up the contents from this virtual machine"? When I built a website on a VPS I just plop the files in, visit the IP address and there it is. That's not going to be the case here. I thought the point of this site was to get answers, not to be told "Oh, you should know this already".

Comment: @cal - as we make VERY clear when you come here this place is for professional sysadmins, there are other places for learners, home users and hackers but this place is for pro's - who inherently know the basics such as this, so you should indeed know this already to post in this site. You've walked into a pilot's lounge and said 'how metal bird be in sky!' - yes JQ was a bit snarky but you've asked a basic dumb question in a place specifically not designed for them, so take your medicine and learn about what this site is and isn't for before posting again please. Oh and he's 100% right too.

Comment: Side note: Comments don't get reputation.

Comment: @Chopper3 I don't seem to see anywhere explicitly saying that this is for professional sysadmins only, but I'll take your word for it and clearly that is the case, so I apologise for the trivial question. Where should I have asked this instead? I considered Stackoverflow as that seems to be the catch all for anything tech related, but decided against it as it's not really programming related per se.

Comment: @Cal Two things, you can see what is on topic for each site in the [help center](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).  Second, you may want to spend some time learning about container technologies like docker.  Container technology is not a VM, but allows you to separate software into an isolated environments.

Comment: @Zoredache - Docker? Isolated? hmmm you sure?

Comment: @Cal Don't apologise... this is a place to ask questions. Everyone has to start somewhere. http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic is clear about what is appropriate and I don't see an issue here. Some people just, well... most of these comments should be removed. Hopefully along with mine. This was an easy question to answer.

Comment: @Chopper3, sure, for some definitions of isolated.  Docker uses LXC, which provides some isolation, similar to a bsd jail.  It certainly isn't as isolated as a full VM, or separate physical hardware.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin: `what kind of steps would I need to follow to achieve this?` - most definitely falls under `product, service, or learning material recommendations` - The OP is essentially asking how to go about doing this. We don't provide step-by-step instructions on how to build websites on a VPS. Feel free to answer if you like but don't disparage those of us who don't and who point out that this question doesn't fit the intent and audience of this site.

Comment: @joeqwerty You're reading far too much into the exact wording I happened to use if that sentence is your reasoning for this being a "product, service, or learning material recommendations" request. I wasn't asking for a step by step list tailored to my specific situation, just to be told that "Oh, look into enabling the XXX module of Apache", or "Try editing Apache's config file to say this". And is the entire purpose of this website not to ask questions about how to go about doing various things...? Can you give an example of a question here that isn't asking how to go about doing something?

Comment: @Cal As the question has been democratically closed, further discussion on this topic should be brought up in http://meta.serverfault.com/ if you feel the need to continue.

Comment: What you describe is called nested virtualization, which you can search the web for. Even on hypervisors that support it, it can carry a 20%-30% CPU performance penalty, depending on workload. It's generally not recommended except for very specific scenarios (which this is not one of).

Answer (score 1):

> So how would I make it so that when someone type mysite.com, Apache
>   (on the host machine) looks at the virtual host configuration for
>   mysite.com and goes "Right, I need to serve up the contents from this
>   virtual machine"?

You wouldn't, because that's not how it's done. You'd start with a dedicated virtual machine for this website/application. As ceejayoz stated, you don't host a virtual machine on a virtual machine.

Forget this idea of hosting a virtual machine on your VPS. Start with a dedicated, independent virtual machine. Then build your websites and applications on it.